# How can I generate a nicely laid out image including text and a png image?

Tags: graphics, png, svg

I would like to generate an image which incorporates some text, nicely laid out with a nice font, and a png image which has to be included in the image.

I could put this together quite quickly in GIMP or similar. However: I want to be able to create this image programmatically from some metadata (some details about the text and the PNG) which will vary, while the basic format of the image will stay the same. The idea is to be able to commit the script to create the image into version control, to use a Makefile, etc. The image to be included is a QR code, which unfortunately I cannot generate on-the-fly from data - I have to use a pre-made PNG for technical reasons.

Now, if I didn't have to include the PNG, I could do this nicely by generating an SVG file which lays out the text properly, and can be rendered into other formats. I know how to do most of the formatting in LaTeX, however I am not sure is this is the best option, as my layout is very custom and un-documentlike, with no margins, weird text spacing etc., and I only want a single image. I think that TeX could work for this, but I have no knowledge of it or where to start with this. Furthermore, I ideally want a PNG as output, which I'm not sure will work with either TeX or LaTeX...

Should I use one of these tools, and what is the best way to do so? Any other ideas of how to do this or what to use?

Comment: The [standalone](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class and [PGF/TikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) will get you started, I think.

Comment: Standalone seems a good option here; look at the `convert=png` option (remember to use `-shell-escape`)

Comment: Not a TeX answer but maybe suited to your application: use imagemagick http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/

Comment: @Bordaigorl, this would be a good solution for including one image in another and doing the conversion, but I wouldn't be able to lay out text with it, would I?

Comment: @jwg for simple captions and annotations the [link above](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#annotating) shows how you can with ImageMagick. However it does not have any advanced typographic capabilities (but neither does GIMP, AFAIK)

Comment: @Bordaigorl I will definitely look at this, thanks.